# How to get data from http protected URL

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, mxml, trac

so I have a Track system with some kind of protection. So to  get some data from any URL you have to pass protection like this http://188.134.14.27/projects/cloudobserver/login and then (in browser) you can see some pages http://188.134.14.27/projects/cloudobserver/wiki/CloudObserverCMSSetup (if you havent passed login youll get no content)
so how to login and get data from page using flash/actionscript (btw I am triing to create an rss reader)?

Comment: your question is more about trac, not sure if you can http post your security to get in or not. you may want to re-tag your question with the [trac] tag to see if more trac orianted people can answer it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think this has something to do with crossdomain.xml file

Answer (score 0):

You need to determine the type of the authentication your webapp uses. If it's cookies, you may try to use something like this:

1. Attempt to login.
2. If the attempt is successful,
   webapp will return a cookie. Save
   this cookie.
3. Every subsequent request to the
   webapp, supply the authentication
   cookie, so that the app knows that you've authenticated.

Does this make sense to you?